# Jabber client that supports client-certificate based authentication

Tags: authentication, xmpp, client-certificates

This is a little odd.

I'm working on improving Pidgin, trying to add client-certificate based authentication for jabber.  I set up an openfire server (which supports client-certificate based authentication), but I want to make sure I set it up correctly - test it with a client that I *know* works.  And for that, I need a client that already supports client-certificate based authentication.

I suppose this is how testing meets dependency hell.

Anyone know of a jabber client I can use to test my openfire setup, so I can get back to testing my code against the openfire server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [Swift](http://swift.im/) and [Gajim 0.14](http://gajim.org/) support certificate authentication. The first on the login screen (yellow shiny button), the second in the account settings window under "Client Certificate".

Comment: adding `jitsi` and `pidgin` to this list.

Comment: removing `pidgin` from this list.